# Deactivate Reply Mail Management

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm triying to deactivated the RMM conf but i can't leave it blank because are mandatory fields, how can i deactivated this option? i don't need any RMM right now.

thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave all the fields as they were, and just mark `DNS Record Redirect Complete` as `No`, this will prevent RMM from working.
Not intuitive, but that’s the only way to do it.

Doc: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000334136&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!